# Remove by _id in MongoDB console

Tags: mongodb

In the MongoDB console how can I remove a record by id? Here's my collection :

```
[ 
  {
     "_id" : { "$oid" : "4d512b45cc9374271b02ec4f" },
     "name" : "Gazza"
  },
  {
     "_id" : { "$oid" : "4d513345cc9374271b02ec6c" },
     "name" : "Dave",
     "adminOf" : { },
     "email" : "email@email.com"
  }
]
```

And here are the commands I've tried that don't work :

```
db.test_users.remove( {"_id":{"$oid":new ObjectId("4d512b45cc9374271b02ec4f")}});
db.test_users.remove( {"_id":{"$oid":"4d513345cc9374271b02ec6c"}});
db.test_users.remove( {"_id":"4d512b45cc9374271b02ec4f"});
db.test_users.remove( {"_id":new ObjectId("4d512b45cc9374271b02ec4f")});
```

Removing by name works :

```
db.test_users.remove( {"name":"Gazza"});
```

This is in the browser shell on at [mongodb.org](http://mongodb.org) if that makes any difference.

Comment: None of the solutions worked for me until I added a callback: db.test_users.remove( {"_id": '4d512b45cc9374271b02ec4f'}, function(err, data){});

Comment: I am courious how you succeded to write those documents in your collection , my attempt ended with  "writeError" : {
  "code" : 52,
  "errmsg" : "$oid is not valid for storage."
 }

Comment: we need to write it in this way to make it work

 db.student.remove({ "_id" : ObjectId("627f593641bcd9e215bc949d")})

  OUTPUT: WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 1 })

Answer (score 332):

Very close. This will work:

```
db.test_users.deleteOne( {"_id": ObjectId("4d512b45cc9374271b02ec4f")});
```

i.e. you don't need a **new** for the ObjectId.

Also, note that in some drivers/tools, `remove()` is now deprecated and `deleteOne` or `deleteMany` should be used instead.

Comment: it will work also without quotes around _id  
db.test_users.remove( {_id: ObjectId("4d512b45cc9374271b02ec4f")});

Comment: I tried this:
TimeAndSpace.remove( {"_id": ObjectId("8Bd2dZ778LXejYNrL")});
...and I got, "Uncaught ReferenceError: ObjectId is not defined
    at <anonymous>:2:13"

Comment: @BClay The object ID expects hexadecimal input (maybe also lowercase) so it's failing on the X, Z characters amongst others.

Comment: If the `_id` field is not automatically generated (i.e. it is not an ObjectId, but a String), You can just write the value of the `_id` under quotation marks: `db.your.database.remove({"_id": "your value"})`.

Comment: DeprecationWarning: collection.remove is deprecated. Use deleteOne, deleteMany, or bulkWrite instead

Answer (score 23):

If you would like to remove by a list of IDs this works great.

```
db.CollectionName.remove({
    "_id": {
        $in: [
            ObjectId("0930292929292929292929"),
            ObjectId("0920292929292929292929")
        ]
     }
})
```

Answer (score 20):

Well, the _id is an object in your example, so you just need to pass an object

```
'db.test_users.remove({"_id": { "$oid" : "4d513345cc9374271b02ec6c" }})'
```

Comment: I tried that too it didn't remove the record: db.test_users.remove( {"_id":{"$oid":"4d513345cc9374271b02ec6c"}}); ps: updated the question to show this

Comment: In your question you said you tried this: db.test_users.remove( {"_id":{"$oid":new ObjectId("4d512b45cc9374271b02ec4f")}});

Comment: Yes I updated the question just now thanks, I've tried both and neither work. Maybe this is because you can't delete on a sub property?

Comment: using that way returns "unknown operator: $oid"

Comment: remove is deprecated now, instead use deleteOne or deleteMany

Answer (score 17):

The answer is that the web console/shell at mongodb.org behaves differently and not as I expected it to. An installed version at home worked perfectly without problem ie; the auto generated _id on the web shell was saved like this :

```
"_id" : { "$oid" : "4d512b45cc9374271b02ec4f" },
```

The same document setup at home and the auto generated _id was saved like this :

```
"_id" : ObjectId("4d5192665777000000005490")
```

Queries worked against the latter without problem.

Comment: Are you sure that they're saved differently in the document BSON? Those differences look like it's the client just formatting the output differently.

Answer (score 8):

first get the ObjectID function from the mongodb
ObjectId = require(mongodb).ObjectID;

then you can call the _id with the delete function

"_id" : ObjectId("4d5192665777000000005490")

Answer (score 8):

Do you have multiple mongodb nodes in a replica set?

I found (I am using via Robomongo gui mongo shell, I guess same applies in other cases) that the correct remove syntax, i.e.

```
db.test_users.remove({"_id": ObjectId("4d512b45cc9374271b02ec4f")})
```

...does not work unless you are connected to the *primary* node of the replica set.

Answer (score 7):

I've just bumped into this myself and this variation worked for me:

```
db.foo.remove({**_id**: new ObjectId("4f872685a64eed5a980ca536")})
```

Answer (score 5):

```
db.collection("collection_name").deleteOne({_id:ObjectId("4d513345cc9374271b02ec6c")})
```

Comment: Please explain why/how this solves the problem. See [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 4):

Suppose we have this dummy collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ea53fedaa79db20d4e14284"), "item" : "planner", "qty" : 75 }
```

simply use:

```
db.inventory.deleteOne({ _id: ObjectId("5ea53fedaa79db20d4e14284") })
```

it will be deleted with this as a response:

```
{ "acknowledged" : true, "deletedCount" : 1 }
```

Comment: I have a document _id: ObjectId("6388df8324ce3a0e5c22b102") and other elements/fields.  In my code I have projects.deleteOne_id({_id: ObjectId(id)} , where id = '6388df8324ce3a0e5c22b102'. When I run this I get an error data
: 
{msg: 'ObjectId is not defined'}, If I try without "ObjectId" I get acknowledged: true, deletedCount: 0. Not deleting.

Answer (score 3):

Even though this post is outdated, **collection.remove is deprecated!** `collection.delete_one` should be used instead!

More information can be found [here under #remove](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
db.getCollection("test_users").deleteOne({_id: new ObjectId("4d512b45cc9374271b02ec4f")})
```

Attribution : To be fair this was the syntax used by a GUI client, the "Russian" one. Mine was a lurking duplicate cause by a bad "upsert" w/o the _id. It only showed up when adding a unique index.

Answer (score 1):

1- C:\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongo (do not issue command yet because you are not connected to any database yet, you are only connected to database server mongodb).

2-

```
> show dbs
analytics_database  0.000GB
local               0.000GB
test_database       0.000GB
```

3-

```
> use test_database
switched to db test_database
```

4-

```
> db.Collection.remove({"_id": ObjectId("5694a3590f6d451c1500002e")}, 1);
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 1 })
>
```

now you see `WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 1 })` is 1 not 0.

Answer (score 1):

Execute the remove() method in this way

```
db.student.remove({ "_id" : ObjectId("627f593641bcd9e215bc949d")})
OUTPUT : WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 1 })
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is new syntax. No need to pass keyword object Id. Just pass like this:

```
db.orders.remove({"_id":"62514d42f5aec503b2e0f2a9"})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a new way to delete the object key(**ObjectId**) i.e. store in **_id** column

- `const ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId`
- `db.collection.deleteOne({_id:**new ObjectId(id)**}) // without double quotes`