# how can i find one record with the filter _id and update that record using the nodejs and mongodb,mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, insert, updates

I was trying to update a student record to mongo db using nodejs. I used the method find One And Update my filter is studentId, student is my schema instance which have the doc for updating. I tried the below code but got error as typeerror  student.findOneAndUpdate is not a function.

```
var student = new Student();
student._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_eId);
student.name = name;
student.studentId = id;
student.status = status;
updateToDb(student);

function updateToDb(student){ 
    console.log(student._id+'      studentId')
    var studentId = student._id;
    var filter = { _id: studentId };
    student.findOneAndUpdate(filter,(err,student)=> {
       if(!err){
        console.log('insertion to db sucess')  
       }
       else{
          console.log('insertion failed '+err);
       }
    })
}
```

Comment: what is this `student` ? Is that incoming request from an API call or an instance of mongoose model or result of DB `.find()` call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with your code is you're trying to club two different functionalities given in Mongoose [.save()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) which works on mongoose model's instances i.e; documents & [.findOneAndUpdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) which works directly on mongoose models.

So if you've all the filters & changes you would directly use `.findOneAndUpdate()` function on mongoose model to update an existing document :

```
let student = {
  _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_eId),
  name: name,
  studentId: id,
  status: status,
};

updateToDb(student);

/** passing in .Js Object as input */
function updateToDb(studentInput) {
  console.log(studentInput._id + " studentId");
  var studentId = studentInput._id;
  var filter = { _id: studentId };
  delete studentInput._id; // Deleting `_id` from studentInput as it shouldn't be there in update object
  Student.findOneAndUpdate(filter, studentInput, (err, student) => {
    if (!err) {
      console.log("insertion to db sucess");
    } else {
      console.log("insertion failed " + err);
    }
  });
}
```

So with `.findOneAndUpdate()` we'll pass `{ multi : true }` option to insert a new document if no document has matched with filter part. But with `.save()` we can actually use it for new insert & updates as well, If `_id` exists in input request & a document in DB matches with it then `.save()` will be considered as update operation otherwise it will treated as insert operation, But it doesn't work on mongoose models it will only work on instances of mongoose models.

```
/** Here since you're passing in instance of mongoose model then use .save() */
var student = new Student();
student._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_eId);
student.name = name;
student.studentId = id;
student.status = status;
updateToDb(student);

function updateToDb(student) {
  console.log(student._id + "      studentId");
  student.save((err, student) => {
    if (!err) {
      console.log("insertion to db sucess");
    } else {
      console.log("insertion failed " + err);
    }
  });
```

Ideally `.save()` is used on updates when you first read a document from DB & then make necessary changes, as mongoose tracks changes occurring to document at the end all you need to do is to apply `.save()` on that doc.

Comment: is there any possibility to delete one record and insert a record in same function?

Comment: how to delete a record with specified objectId

Comment: @jiss : You can't delete & insert in same function, maybe after deletion in callback you can do another DB call to insert doc ! But what are you trying to do here ? Is it like deletion & insertion for same doc ? Check this :: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932928/remove-by-id-in-mongodb-console)